# Generating height map from a single image of shadows using python

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, heightmap, pbr

i'm currently developing a web app with python based for generating a set of PBR texture. and stuck on the height map generation. i've been searching for this problem for a few weeks and still haven't find any answer yet. is there's any method to generate a height map from a single image, or it's just not possible.

for reference, this is how i want to achieve the result. i've tried to applying gaussian blur but it seems not just that simple.

[left, original. right, height map generated by Materialize by bounding box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckqsQ.jpg):

[image: original]
[image: height map]

Comment: Yeah, it’s definitely not that simple. You can make educated guesses for the height, but there’s lots of uncertainty

Comment: If you could know depth from one camera we would not have evolved 2 eyes....

Comment: but maybe there's a way to do it, since the app i've used for generating the second image is only require one image for the result. but i can't find which code in their repository that contain the process

Comment: @AnderBiguri: this is not quite true. With a single eye we keep some perception of depth, partly by focusing.

Comment: Quick & dirty way: take the heights to be the gray values of the pixels. This will give you a terrain-like surface that has "some resemblance" to the ground truth.

Comment: less quick but still dirty way: assume a simple reflectance model, light coming from somewhere, then turn the pixels into surface normals, then integrate. since you only have one dimension (illumination) to estimate a surface normal (two dimensions), this will be insufficient. => a single image is likely not enough. this probably requires some numericla optimization.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i do aware of the method, by using light intensity is the only thing for extracting the height value, but i can't find how to blur the image like the reference image. regular gaussian just not even close to the result. and thanks for you guys responses, i appreciate it!

Comment: could be the sum of a few bandpasses. impossible to say without you explaining where that came from, with usable details. "materialize by bounding box" doesn't mean anything to me. a quick google tells me it's an unfortunately-named program by an unfortunately-named company, for artistic purposes. you just want art, do whatever looks pleasing. if you want engineering, the data is insufficient and you will get guesswork at best.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, there is a technique known as "shape from shading" that can reconstruct a height field from reflected intensities, by assuming a Lambertian reflectance model.

But this is difficult and inaccurate, and can be deceived by the color of the rocks not being uniform and by cast shadows.

---

**Short answer**: don't even try.

Comment: since i don't really aim for the accuracy, it might work for me. and is this method have a relation to "inverse square law" by any chance? because both seems works with light intensity. i'll catch you up later for the result, thanks for your response.

Comment: @MukminArrijal: "inverse square law": not really. For your image, the distance is constant.